# How to add limited bone movement dependent on movement of other bones

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

So I imported a character mesh with a rig that has a lot of body parts tied to bones. I want to set the rig up so that if bones are moved certain bones will move in certain ways, for example if the arm is lifted the chest muscles are stretched and the shoulder rotates.
[image]
I think the best way to do that would be to use drivers on the bones that are supposed to follow, but I want to limit how the bone follows, i.e. when the arm lifts up I only want the shoulder to rotate a little and when the arm is lowered I don't want the shoulder to rotate at all. I tried using limit rotation and location restraints but that means the shoulder won't rotate evenly with the arm movement but will move quickly and then stop before the arm movement is finished. Would be cool if I could somehow script the driver to tell it what to do and when but I have no experience with scripting, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use ActionConstraints and also AnimationNodes_scripts to create your desired effect

Comment: @MohammadHosseinJamshidi Oh okay, is there somewhere you can get template scripts, or maybe you know a good tutorial that explains how to use them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that action constraint can do the job for you but for doing it by animation nodes, take a look at [documentaion](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/subprograms/script/) and this [short video](https://youtu.be/QQKJBu4LV4E). Addressing to bones in blender is by names and so is not robust for the case of name changes.